# How to get part of the filename using (basename "${video%.*}") in bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a set of videos scalled xxxyyys.mp4, each filename ends with s. I want to execute a script that takes only the name upto xxxyyy for the argument basefile.

So far, what I have is

```
for video in folder/*
do 
  python script.py -i "${video%*.mp4}" --basefile $(basename "${video%.*}") 
done
```

How do I edit this to get only the name upto xxxyyy?

Comment: This not working --> `"${video%s.*}"`  ?

Comment: Ah, I feel like an idiot! Yes, it worked thank you very much.

Comment: @user42 you need to quote `"$(basename "${video%s.*}")"` or only the basename will be quoted and not the `--basefile`. think you can do `"$(basename "$video" s.mp4)"` should yield same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
"${video%s.*}"
```

This will delete everything from (and including) the last `s.` until the end of the string.